# DRY up ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, debouncing

I have a small web-app that accepts `input` from a human to create search params. I'm using `ng-model-options` to debounce the `ng-change` function to execute the search.

I have small arrows next to the column names on the table that lets users sort (there are three icons - `up-down`, `up`, and `down` for the sort_field and sort_order displayed using `ng-class`) ; I would like to register a change on those and execute a search after a small delay using debounce. The problem is I'm not sure how use `ng-model` to bind the particular param to those icons. I don't want someone hammering on the sort icons and crashing the server or their browser.

What I would rather do is have one place on the page that says to watch the `search_param` object and fire a search 500 milliseconds after whenever it has changed. This way any of the input fields or sort selections would be called when a user is done editing them which triggers a function to send those params to the endpoint.

What is the strategy in AngularJS to do this? Right now all input fields bind a field in the `search_param` object and have `ng-model-options` to debounce on change. This is a lot of repeated code.

Comment: Do you use the same function for `ng-change` everywhere? In that case you could use `$timeout`, and if there isn't any search in queue, you could start one with `$timeout`. If there is, just cancel the `$timeout` and start a new one.

Answer (score 0):

I recently answered someone regarding Tables and the amount of effort and work you have to put in to get very basic functionality (sorting,searching,pagination).

Why re-invent the wheel if there is a perfectly great library for you to use:
**Angular-datatables**

I posted a complete solution here for you to use pulling data from a json source: [Ng-repeat trying to create a counter index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37286108/ng-repeat-trying-to-create-a-counter-index/37288791#37288791)

In your case you would need to go through the Server side processing documentation on Datatable's site to correctly format the data: https://datatables.net/manual/server-side